# block quotes not rendered properly in readme.md

Tags: markdown

I am creating my readme file on github. I want to highlight text like : 
"We have graph structure in `Map<Integer,List<Pair<Integer,String>>>` format. "

But it is rendered as on github :
"We have graph structure in `Map>>` format. "

Can anyone explain what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue It was because a new line is required after #heading.Before I had

## Dependency Construct

We have graph structure in Map>> format.

Now I changed it to:

## Dependency Construct

We have graph structure in Map>> format.

Just a new line was all it required.